# C# thread issue, I can't function is not working correct which is called in Events_DataReceived

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

```
private void Events_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedFromServerEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                txtInfo.Text += $"Server: {BitConverter.ToString(e.Data)}{Environment.NewLine}";
                tcp2rtu_Response(e.Data);   // TODO: Test et.
            });
            mbRcvDataMngr();
        }

        catch (InvalidOperationException exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
        }

        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

> The method I wrote `tcp2rtu_Response()`, is for parsing `e.Data` and filling  `public byte [] ReceiveBuffer`. But it's not filling the `ReceiveBuffer[]` and not turning back to `mbRcvDataMngr()` method, in `Events_DataReceived()`.

I used Invoke to fill `txtInfo` it works ok, but not working with `tcp2rtu_Response()`.

```
public void tcp2rtu_Response(byte[] tcpReceived) 
    {
        ReceiveBuffer[0] = tcpReceived[6];
        ReceiveBuffer[1] = tcpReceived[7];
        for(int i = 8; i <= tcpReceived.Length; i++) 
        {
            ReceiveBuffer[i - 6] = tcpReceived[i];      
        }
    }
```

What should I do, any suggestions?

Comment: Could please you provide more information about the error you are experiencing? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the full context but hope that helps: if you are changing the value of any field or variable which is bound with the UI, should be done by using the UI Thread (Dispatcher), otherwise this may crash if other thread different than Dispatcher one tries to update it.

What I come up with is that `Invoke()` method is executing the action asynchronously. So when `mbRcvDataMngr()` is called there is a concurrency issue. You could try to ensure that invoked action is awaited, then when task is continuated, response has already been processed.

Comment: Thanks for attention. I've solved the problem. Actually that's just, for loop condition error.
 solved just like that. `for (int i = 8; i < tcpReceived.Length; i++)`